# Write a File to the Http Response from a class library

Tags: c#, asp.net

I am not able to write any file using `MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(Response.OutputStream)` using C# Asp.net MVC because it is producing an exception stating the "Response is null". But the same code is working in Controller when contained within the controller

I want to use a separate class for the downloading method.

Answer (score 1):

The most simple way is for a method on your class to take a parameter of type `System.IO.Stream`

```
public class MyClass
{
    ...
    public class WriteMyMemoryStreamTo(Stream outStream)
    {
       MyMemoryStream.WriteTo(outStream);
    }
}
```

And then in your controller method

```
myClassInstance.WriteMyMemoryStream(Response.OutputStream);
```